# Why do some letters or escape sequences not render correctly in urxvt?

Tags: zsh, urxvt, x-resources

With a special combination of shell (zsh w/ syntax hightlighting), terminal (urxvt) and configuration with Xresources, I noticed a strange issue with font rendering that only seems to occur with some bold characters (AKA bold escape sequences) like the letter 'k' -- it will show up as a tall, empty vertical rectangle (see picture below):

[image: terminal shows strange font rendering]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Post your configuration! (Especially the fonts but do post all applicable resources.)

Comment: @Gilles I actually know the answer to this, but didn't realize that I had to wait to self-answer since I didn't have an account for this exchange :) (I'm only minimally active on SO)

*Spoiler:* The culprit is the letterSpace resource being set to -1 in Xresources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the letterSpace configuration in the .Xresources file, which sets letterSpace to -1 (or lower) like:

```
! /home/username/.Xresources

URxvt*letterSpace: -1
```

Many users and blog posts will suggest changing the letterSpace option to -1 to adjust for kerning, but there seems to be a side effect in this situation where urxvt can't render the glyph.

Comment: I can add that I needed to set letterSpace to at least 4, to make URxvt show the characters ★ and ▶ using Envy Code R, which I use in my prompt. Unfortunately, that makes all other output rather sparse... and I didn't need this setting before my huge system update.